# GSP select from multiple lists

Tags: grails, gsp

Given two similar domains `Foo` and `Bar`, is it possible to create a `g:select` tag that can choose from both of them?  E.g.,

```
<g:select from="${[Foo.list(), Bar.list()]}"/>
```

That, unfortunately, does not work. It creates a single option that is the text of all items from both domains :|

So, does anybody know if this can be done?

**Edit**

Nope, it doesn't make any difference to pass this list in from the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<g:select from="${Foo.list() + Bar.list()}"/>
```

would also do just fine

Comment: Nice! A little bit less punctuation to stare at.  Thanks.

Comment: what can be more natural that a "+" if you want to COMBINE something? :)

Comment: True! I just tend to avoid overloaded operators because they're not always consistently implemented.

Comment: you can also write `${Foo.list().plus( Bar.list() )}`

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, just needed to `flatten` the list!

```
<g:select from="${[Foo.list(), Bar.list()].flatten()}"/>
```

Otherwise, it was a list of lists.